# Wait for .map() to finish, check returned array, then render results in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have a div in which I map through an array and return components with rendered results. For each array value I do an API call, multiple checks, and calculations, and, if the calculations are correct, I return the final JSX, if not, I return nothing.

The main component look like this:

```
export const FinalComponent = ({ items }) => {
return (
    <div>
        {items.map((item) => (
            <ItemComponent data={item} />
        ))}
    <div>
    ); 
};
```

The Item component looks like this:

```
export default function ItemComponent({ data }) {
  const [returnedItem, setReturnedItem] = useState(null);

  // API CALL SETS returnedItem

  // Necessary checks and calculations

  // If check length is more then 0, return component
  if (check > 0) {
      return (
          <div>
            <p>{returnedItem.name}</p>
          </div>
      );
   }
}
```

This works as it should. The problem is, let's say in the "items" array I have 3 items and I go through each of them, but none of them goes through check and in the end, I return nothing. What I want, is if that scenario happens I want to show one message "Data not found". How can I wait for all .map items to finish and check the final .map array if there is no returned component in there?

Comment: What do you mean by *"...wait for all `.map` items to finish..."*? `Array`'s `map` is a synchronous function, you wait for it to finish to calling it and getting its return value. If you're doing something asynchronous in the `map` call, you'll need to provide more information for us to be able to help you. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: re `// API CALL SETS returnedItem` - do that inside a useEffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function to your child component `ItemComponent` which marks a state of the parent component `FinalComponent` as true if some children have 'check' greater than 0. Then, you can check if that state is not marked as true to render "Data not found".

```js
export default function ItemComponent({ data, handleCheck }) {
  const [returnedItem, setReturnedItem] = useState(null);

  // An API call that sets the value of 'returnedItem'

  // Perform necessary checks and calculations

  // If the check length is more than 0, return the component
  if (check > 0) {
      // Call the 'handleCheck' function with 'true' to indicate that an item passed the checks
      handleCheck(true);

      return (
          <div>
            <p>{returnedItem.name}</p>
          </div>
      );
   }
}
```

```js
export const FinalComponent = ({ items }) => {
  const [someItemHasChecked, setSomeItemHasChecked] = useState(false);

  // Define a 'handleCheck' function to receive check results
  const handleCheck = (check) => {
    setSomeItemHasChecked(check);
  }

  return (
      <div>
          {items.map((item) => (
              // Pass the 'handleCheck' function as a prop to the 'ItemComponent'
              <ItemComponent data={item} handleCheck={handleCheck} />
          ))}

          {someItemHasChecked ? (
              // At least one item passed the checks
              null
          ) : (
              // No item passed the checks
              <div>Data not found</div>
          )}
      </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you could do is follow the "Presentational and Container Component pattern" as described in this article by [Dan Abramov](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

Personally, I'd keep `ItemComponent` as a presentational component, and keep `FinalComponent` as a container component.

Inside `FinalComponent` Id do all the calculations for all of the data, and stick the result in an array of finalised data. Then you could do `data.map` on the already calculated data - that way `ItemComponent` could receive just the data to display.